# Cisco ASA multiple dynamic VPN support (defaultRAGroup-defaultl2lGroup)

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-ios, cisco-ios-15

### Question (short)

How to set up 2 totally different dynamic l2l vpn tunnels on an ASA5506

#### Question (extended)

We have a Cisco ASA5506 Security Appliance and we want to set up 2 dynamic VPN setups.

- Tunnel for various windows clients;
- Tunnel to a branch office with dynamic ip using DynDNS.

We can set up the tunnels individually without a problem but cant get them working both at once.

### VPN 1 (windows clients)

**`Cisco ASA5506 config`**

```
group-policy l2tp-ipsec_policy internal

group-policy l2tp-ipsec_policy attributes
  dns-server value 10.100.3.1
  vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec            
  default-domain value vbv.local

  banner value U bent nu aangemeld op het netwerk, zet uw VPN verbinding uit wanneer u klaar bent.
  wins-server value 10.100.3.1
  dns-server value 10.100.3.1
  vpn-filter value VBV_VPN_CLIENT_FILTER
  split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
  split-tunnel-network-list value VBV_VPN_CLIENTS  
exit

tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
  default-group-policy l2tp-ipsec_policy
  address-pool POOL-VPN_VBVLOCAL        
  authentication-server-group VBV_LDAP LOCAL
  password-management
  strip-realm
exit    

tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
  pre-shared-key *****
exit

tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
  authentication pap
  no authentication chap
  no authentication ms-chap-v1
  no authentication ms-chap-v2
exit

crypto ipsec transform-set winClient esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec transform-set winClient mode transport

crypto dynamic-map dynWinVPN 500 set ikev1 transform-set winClient

crypto map cmap_WAN-GLASVEZEL 500 ipsec-isakmp dynamic dynWinVPN


crypto isakmp enable WAN-GLASVEZEL

crypto isakmp policy 10
  authentication pre-share
  encryption 3des
  hash sha
  group 2
  lifetime 86400
exit

access-list VBV_VPN_CLIENT_FILTER extended permit object-group obj-VBVLOCAL_VPN_AllowedServices any any log notifications
access-list VBV_VPN_CLIENTS extended permit ip object-group obj-VBVLOCAL_VPN_AllowedNetworks any
```

Above on itself working perfectly, i know about the PAP auth but the reason is the LDAP verification. (cant get that working with mschapv2 and is of later concern).

### VPN 2 (site to site to branch office)

**`Cisco ASA5506 config`**

```
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac

crypto dynamic-map ***.dyndns.org 100 set pfs group1
crypto dynamic-map ***.dyndns.org 100 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
crypto dynamic-map ***.dyndns.org 100 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto dynamic-map ***.dyndns.org 100 set security-association lifetime kilobytes 9216000

crypto map cmap_WAN-GLASVEZEL 100 ipsec-isakmp dynamic ***.dyndns.org

crypto ikev1 policy 2
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
!

tunnel-group ***.dyndns.org type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group ***.dyndns.org general-attributes
 default-group-policy grpPol_vbvjb
tunnel-group ***.dyndns.org ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
 peer-id-validate nocheck
!
```

---

**`Branch office Cisco 881 router`**

```
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr 3des
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp policy 2
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key ****** address ***
crypto isakmp invalid-spi-recovery
crypto isakmp keepalive 15
!
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 9216000
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 86400
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto map SDM_CMAP-***_BACKUP 1 ipsec-isakmp
 description TUNNEL-***_BACKUP_****
 set peer *****
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
 set pfs group1
 match address 171
!
access-list 171 remark VPN-IPSEC-***_BACKUP
access-list 171 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 10.100.0.0 0.0.3.255 log
access-list 177 permit icmp any host 10.100.3.1
```

Same story here, fully working on its own but can't combine with the setup from above.

So in short, i can set up both VPN setups and get them working but i cannot get them working in one configuration.

#### Keynotes

- Works seperately but not toghether;
- Branch office uses dynDNS because it has no static IP;
- Windows VPN Clients use 2l2 with ldap server verification;
- Strange this i see is site2site uses defaultRAGroup and clients defaultl2lgroup.
- How can i check catch correct crypto dynamic map?

Hope someone in here can help so we do not have to call Cisco TAC.

Comment: Nobody? BTW we need a 3rd dynamic one too :|

Comment: Can you specify "does not work"? Maybe including log + debug output in your question may enable somebody to help you.

Comment: I am not on location at the moment but on monday i will add some syslog files. The thing i know that is going wrong is that when i use l2l i am unable to enter a group en thus i cannot have the asa know at which group it belongs, it all comes in on the defaultl2l or defaultragroup which is frustrating. Before we used the cisco client which we can assign ipsec groups to, in native windows we cannot and we do not want to use certificates.

Comment: You should engage a Security Architect/Engineer to design a scalable solution and troubleshoot your implementations. Well worth the investment for your business.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Sadly i never found an answer. The case was dropped and we did a completely different setup. Maybe this could be helpfull to someone else in the future, but until now no answer was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the crypto map sequence number for the dynamic entry to a higher one  (e.g. >500), see this note:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/ipsec-negotiation-ike-protocols/46242-lan-to-lan-vpn-client.html#crypto

Comment: I can't, this results in wrong tunnels landing on the defaultRAgroup. I want do differentiate different dynamic tunnels which do not have the option of setting a group name AND are dynamic in IP.

Comment: BTW Currently running a case with Cisco TAC

Comment: which was the solution of the Cisco TAC ?